# CodeIgniter, query only shows 1 record in view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new with PHP and using MVC. My script seems to be only showing a single record instead of multiple records even in a foreach loop.

Here's my code:

**Model**

```
public function rp_reach_rate_stmt()
{
    $stmt = $this->db->select(array('user_id','user','full_name'))->get('vicidial_users',10);
    //  $stmt = $this->db->get('vicidial_users',10);
    return $stmt->row();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function rp_reach_rate()
{

    $this->load->model('db_model');
    $data['sqlstmt'] = $this->rp_reach_rate_get_data();
    $this->load->view('RP_ReachRate',$data);
}

private function rp_reach_rate_get_data()
{
    $this->load->model('db_model');
    $result = $this->db_model->rp_reach_rate_stmt();
    return $result;
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
    var_dump($sqlstmt);echo '<br />';
    foreach($sqlstmt as $row)
    {
        echo  $row." ";

    }
?>
```

**RESULT**

> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user"]=>
>   string(4) "6666" ["full_name"]=> string(5) "Admin" }
>
> 1 6666 Admin

I might have missed something.

Comment: Not a codeigniter user but manual says `This method returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. ` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html My guess, use `result`, not `row`.

Comment: fyi - in the get portion you are limiting it to returning 10 records. if you want all the records returned then remove: ,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function rp_reach_rate_stmt()
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->select(array('user_id','user','full_name'))->get('vicidial_users',10);
    //  $stmt = $this->db->get('vicidial_users',10);
        return $stmt->result_array();
    }
```

change `$stmt->row()` to `$stmt->result_array()` as above and test. It will return result with all rows & as array. If you need access as object then use `result()` instead of `result_array()`

Comment: Hi, will try this out. thanks for the fast response. :)

Comment: No im having an Array to String conversion error. 
I need to figure out this bit of right here inside the view

foreach($sqlstmt as $row)
   {
    echo  $row." ";

   }

Comment: `echo $row['DB_coulmn_name']` when use `result_array()`

Comment: Hi, i got it now.

I need to add the index or rows for each row.
"echo $row['user_id'].' ';
    echo $row['user'].' '; 
    echo $row['full_name'].' ';
    echo '<br />';"

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is now RESOLVED!